# ¿Como puedo mostrar un error 404 en una aplicación JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con `jsf` y me encuentro con un problema:

Necesito que de alguna forma (si se puede desde el código en la web),cuando ocurra un error en el aplicativo me muestre que fue lo que sucedió, que indique el **error** algo como *capturarlo* y *mostrarlo* el problema esta en que el error se muestra en el `output` de `netbeans` pero quiero **capturarlo y mostrarlo en la página**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

si entiendo bien lo que necesitas es que cuando ocurra un error en tu aplicativo este muestre que ocurrio? 
si estas utilizando jsf hay una forma facil de hacerlo agregando unas propiedades en un archivo descriptor llamado **web.xml** si estas usando jsf deberías tenerlo en el **web-content/web-inf** de tu pagina.

hay que saber primero que existen muchos tipos de error que se pueden presentar a la hora de ejecutar tu aplicacion puedes ver [aqui](https://hipertextual.com/2015/10/codigos-de-error-en-la-web)

Para configurar los solo debes agregar la propiedad `<error-page>` dentro el archivo descriptor **web.xml**
con esta propiedad `<error-page>` indicas que una pagina establecida por ti funcionara como una de *error* con la propiedad `<error-code>` estableces el tipo de error que mostrara esta pagina y con `<location>`  estableces la dirección en la que se encuentra la *pagina* 
todo esto significa que cuando se ejecute un error por ejemplo **500** para mostrar este deberás establecer tu pagina de error **500** :

```
<error-page>

   <error-code>500</error-code>
    <!--dentro del web-content de tu aplicacion -->
    <location>/errorPages/pageError500.html</location> 

 </error-page>
```

puedes agregar las paginas de error que necesites de acuerdo a los tipos de errores existentes

para averiguar sobre la configuracion de archivo **web.xml** mira [aqui](http://re-orientation.com/configuracion-webxml-declaracion-de-frameworks)

Comment: eso significa que si cambio la seccion de codigo <error-code>500</error-code> por <error-code>404</error-code> mostrara el error 404 de la aplicacion?

Comment: puedes cambiarlo por el error que necesites mira los errores posibles en  https://hipertextual.com/2015/10/codigos-de-error-en-la-web creo que encontraras lo que necesitas